# Is "cachorro" (for an animal) also used in Portugal?

Tags: português-europeu, uso-de-palavras, diferenças-transatlânticas

My understanding was that "cachorro" is Brazilian and "cão" is European. Now I've seen "um cachorro quente" (a "hot-dog" I presume) in a book of European Portuguese. So, is "cachorro" in Portugal only used for this type of meal or is it also a typical word for an animal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "cachorro" is used in Portugal, but it means a puppy, a young dog.

It is used especially of baby or very young dogs, in which case de diminutive “cachorrinho” is the word usually used.

For adult dogs, the word used is "cão".

[According to the Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cachorro) dictionary:

> ca·chor·ro |ô| (origem duvidosa)
> nome masculino
>
> 1. Cão com menos de seis meses; cão jovem. [imagem]
> 2. [Portugal: Madeira, Brasil]  Cão adulto. [imagem]
> 3. Cria, geralmente não desmamada, de animal semelhante ao cão.
> 4. (...)

"cachorro", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/cachorro [consultado em 15-06-2020].

---

For the hot-dog, both "cachorro" and "cachorro-quente" are used, but the short version is preferred - for brevity.

Comment: I use *cachorrinho* for a very young dog only. Haven't you ever heard, "Ainda é cachorro?" about an almost, but not quite, fully-grown dog? I wouldn't call *cachorrinho* to one of those.

Comment: I think you're right, @Jacinto. I think of "cachorro" as a sort of adolescent-dog, and cachorrinho as a sort of baby-dog. I'm not sure how to include this in the answer.

Comment: Feel free to do that edit, and if you bother to do it you can make it community-wiki. :)

Comment: Fiz uma edição minimalista. Retirei a referência a "puppy" vs. "pup". Os dicionários dizem que são sinónimos. Vê se tá bem. Eu não fazia community-wiki; foi uma coisita de nada.

Comment: @Jacinto Tá bom. 

Answer (score 4):

In Portugal is most used "cachorro" for the "hot-dog" and "cão" for the animal, but "cachorro" is also used for animals, generally "cachorrinho" for a puppy dog.

In Brazil it most used "cachorro" for the animal and "cachorro quente" for "hot-dog". 
"cão" is not so common, and in some regions "cão" can even mean a very restless person, who does a lot of mess, for example "esse garoto é um cão", something like "this boy is a dog".

Comment: Olá Ricardo, bem-vindo. Podes editar a tua resposta para também responder à pergunta primária? Não pareces abordar a parte principal da pergunta: "Is “cachorro” (for an animal) also used in Portugal?"

Comment: obrigado pela dica, editei a resposta

Comment: Bem vindo Ricardo! a pergunta foi feita em Inglês, talvez a pessoa que o fez não tenha conhecimento em Português o suficiente para entender tua resposta. Terias como escrevê-la em Inglês, por obséquio?

Comment: entendi, obrigado @gmauch, traduzido ;)

Comment: Nas novelas elas dizem muito "você e um cachorro"

Comment: I think it's very common to say rather "esse garoto é **o** cão", with "cão" meaning the devil; calling someone "cachorro" as in "você é um cachorro" is similar to calling someone a "scumbag", @ClMend .